# conditional viewport meta tag in index.html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, viewport, meta-tags

I have an angular module with two sub modules in it, one for user and the other for admin. of course they share the same `index.html` file.

in my user module I would like to have the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the `<head></head>` tags in `index.html`

While I want it to be removed in my admin module and just have the desktop view for phones as is.

I tired to do this in the admin first component constructor :

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
this.meta.removeTag('name="viewport"');
```

the tag is being removed but that is after the app started rendering with the existence of this meta tag since it is in `index.html` so it does not give the desired result

any suggestions to have actually add this meta conditionally? 
the hard part is that it should be in the head of index.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you have to manually set the viewport to something else. Try removing the meta tag and setting it to something else, like in this example:

https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2011/06/dynamically_cha.html

If you view the following example from mobile, it will show the response view first (set in the `index.html`) and then after 5 seconds it will show the desktop version.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private readonly meta: Meta
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    timer(5000).subscribe(() => {
      this.meta.removeTag('name="viewport"');
      this.meta.addTag({ name: 'viewport', content: 'width=1000' })
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: this won't work. according to the link it is adding a script in the head in index.html, but in my case the index is shared between user side and admin side, I can not know which side I am on on the index.html file so my script would be applied to both modules.

Comment: It does work. Did you try it? I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: yes it does thanks for the example, so it does not work to only remove the tag but I needed to set a new one! I did not use a timer and it works well, is there a reason why you added it?

Comment: I just used the timer to demonstrate the change. If you make the change in the constructor it will happen so fast you won't see it. Glad I helped!